# Determine subgroup generated by a number

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

so i got this question in a preparation test (http://prntscr.com/jmjs3r).I managed to show the last 2 questions but i got stuck getting a problem with the 1st one.

I started by doing {0,9,18,(18+9=27, so we get 6),15,(15+9=24, so we should(?) get 1?)} and then i stopped since i found a wrong number so the whole subgroup would be different.

Can someone explain where is mistake and why it doesn't work like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Type in or describe the actual problem, please.  It's actually too much to expect people to click external links and scroll to read the problem.  Also the link may be taken down some time in the next few years so people reading your question five  years or a few decades from now won't have access to the question.

Comment: "18+9=27, so we get 6". Because $27 - 24 = 6$?  "15+9=24, so we should(?) get 1?"  Because $24 - 24 = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

$27 - 24 = 3; 27 = 24 + 3$ so $24 \equiv 3 \mod 24$. So you get $3$; not $6$.

$3+9 = 12$

$12 + 9 = 21$

$21 + 9 = 30$

$30 - 24 = 6; 30 = 24 + 6$ so $30 \equiv 6\mod 24$ so you get $6$.

$6+ 9 =15$

$15 + 9 = 24$

$24 - 24 = 0; 24 = 24 + 0$ so $24\equiv 0 \mod 24$ so you get $0$.

That is the entire group.  It has $8$ elements.